# Sanitizing filenames while minding the clash

Tags: php, laravel

I need to sanitize files in PHP/Laravel while minding the clash of the filenames.

What's the easiest method to do it? I need to make separate names like Uber, Ub_er, Ub#er, Über and so on. It doesn't need to be readable, but needs to be deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to sanitize them but keep them different, you can just remove the unwanted character and add the Unix timestamp at the end of the file name. This way, you can see the sanitized filename and you are pretty sure that they are all different.

However, if it's a large scale application and you are working with several servers doing this exact operation, adding an unique id based on the server at the end of the file would be ideal. (however, unless you are sanitizing hundreds of files per second, it shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: adding timestamp will make the names not deterministic, so if user creates a file by input Uber and then Uber# I won't know which one should I load

Comment: @ZbigniewKisły Well, just save them into the database? I'm not sure to understand.

If I put the file ub_er now, I will have uber1624632103. If I put the file ub#er five seconds later, I will have uber1624646508. They are different, so save them as such in the database.

Else, you can just translate the file to hexadecimal code and store that, but you will have an issue if two users try to post a file with the same name at different times.